# Update histogram (kivy) by textinput and button

Tags: python, kivy

I want to update my bins of my histogram by entering a number of bins in a textinput. After entering the value in the textbox the histogram should be updated after clicking on the button.

My code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2Kivy
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("c:/Users/Niels/Desktop/uranite_23_03_2017.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    data = []
    for column in reader:
        data.append(column[1])

    results = data
    results = [int(i) for i in results]

bins = 200
plt.hist(results, bins=bins)
plt.title("Histogram")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")

fig = plt.gcf()
canvas = fig.canvas

def callback(self):

    global fig, results
    #bins = 50
    plt.hist(results,bins=bins)
    canvas.draw()

class HistogramApp(App):
    title = 'Histogram data'

    def build(self):
        fl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.btn1 = Button(text="Update", height=40, size_hint_y=None)
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=callback)

        self.tekstvak = TextInput(height=30, size_hint_y=None, multiline=False)

        nav1 = NavigationToolbar2Kivy(canvas)

        fl.add_widget(nav1.actionbar)
        fl.add_widget(canvas)
        fl.add_widget(self.tekstvak)
        fl.add_widget(self.btn1)
        return fl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HistogramApp().run().
```

The callback function works fine. If I enter the bins manually in this function, the histogram will update like it should. But how can I do it by entering a number in the textinput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `callback` so that it receives the number of bins as an argument, and then provide the TextInput text property when binding the `on_press` event to the button. So, first, the `callback`

```
# Callback takes one argument that is the number of bins
def callback(bins):

    global fig, results
    # Clear the plot figure, otherwise you'll end up with multiple plots overlayed
    plt.clf()
    # Convert bins to integer. You may want to use try/except statements to check if bins is convertable to integer and, if not, handle the exception
    bins = int(bins)
    plt.hist(results,bins=bins)
    canvas.draw()
```

Now the HistogramApp:

```
class HistogramApp(App):
    title = 'Histogram data'

    def build(self):
        fl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        self.btn1 = Button(text="Update", height=40, size_hint_y=None)
        self.tekstvak = TextInput(height=30, size_hint_y=None, multiline=False)
        # Bind the on press event after defining self.tekstvak
        # Note the use of lambda so that we can provide our own
        # argument to the callback. The argument is simply the
        # reference to the TextInput instance text property
        self.btn1.bind(on_press=lambda x: callback(self.tekstvak.text))

        nav1 = NavigationToolbar2Kivy(canvas)

        fl.add_widget(nav1.actionbar)
        fl.add_widget(canvas)
        fl.add_widget(self.tekstvak)
        fl.add_widget(self.btn1)
        return fl
```

You can even bind the same callback to the `on_text_validate` event of TextInput. In this way, you could type the number of bins, press Enter and that's it.

```
self.tekstvak.bind(on_text_validate=lambda x: callback(self.tekstvak.text))
```